# What does Howard know and when does he know it?

Tags: collateral-beauty

In [***Collateral Beauty***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4682786/), does Howard ever figure out his co-workers are gas-lighting him, and if so, when?

Does he know The Real Truth™?

When at the final meeting he says, "I'm disappointed", what is he referring to?

What do his friends think he is referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, he figures it out, that his co-workers are trying to revoke is right to have saying in approval of sale of shares. He figures it out by watching the videos they made of him. In the scene when they play the video of Howard talking to himself he looks at his co-workers, who look down (feeling shame). Also Howard realises they organised people to follow and film him. Secondly they admit doing it and "doing even more".

No, he does not know the real truth and actually his co-workers neither. This questions is partly answered here: [Why are Time, Death & Love only visible to Howard?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69362/why-are-time-death-love-only-visible-to-howard)

Hes not disappointed in them. He says that to Whit and emphasises its not over what they did, but because Whit has distanced himself from his daughter and has not taken matters in his own hand to improve the situation. Howard is disappointing, because as he says from his own experience that: "Tomorrow is not promised".

The point of this scene is, that Whit, Claire and Simon realises that Howard is much more informed of their personal affairs and has not forgotten them. They feel shame how they approached to Howard. But also Howard understands he has been off, acknowledges their effort to company and finally agrees that it is right decision to sell shares, which he has been wayward before.

Comment: What about the videos clue him in?  He already had reason to think he was having hallucinations/visions.  Did something about the video change his mind, or confirm his doubts?

Comment: As far as I understand no. He confirms not being in right state of mind and answers that he is not "talking to people" - he knew that before. Also earlier we have scenes where Howard understands only he sees them - for example office scene when Claire comes in and he talks to Time. It would have not made sense in the movie, if he would have figured it out in this scene. Time, Death and Love were real, but not only to Howard but also to Claire, Whit and Simon. He agrees to sign the papers, because no matter what he says he still looks insane on those tapes.